# Selectable text at Highcharts tooltip

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I need to make possible to copy text from Highcharts tooltip. I'm using `useHTML : true`, and my tooltip appears as HTML table. As I found so far this option is impossible. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is related with non-support `selectable` event on Highcharts elements. The same situation is with title, like here: http://jsfiddle.net/pfrn853b/

You can post your suggestion in our uservoice here: http://highcharts.uservoice.com